# How to get values from key

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am trying to save the value of user_id by writing like this

```
String Stytch_user_id = jsonContent.getKeyValue("user_id");
```

but it says

```
The method getKeyValue(String) is undefined for the type String
```

How can I store the value of user_id correctly.
Thank you very much for your advise.

```
    InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream();
            String jsonContent = convert(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            String Stytch_user_id = jsonContent.getKeyValue("user_id");
```

Inside of jsonContent I have.

```
{
"method_id":"email-test-da81007a--aef293c89f17",
"request_id":"request-id-test-c8c5db947e5",
"status_code":200,
"user_id":"user-test-9848a7bb782eea7b"
}
```

**This is my latest work so far.**

if (http.getResponseCode() == 200) {

```
        InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream();
        String jsonContent = convert(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        RicDoorLoginDao ricDoorLoginDao = new RicDoorLoginDao();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        try {
              JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonContent);
              String Stytch_user_id = node.get("user_id").textValue();
              Object[] objects = getUserLogin(Stytch_user_id, "P0002","123456789", ricDoorLoginDao);
              
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    } else { 
        System.out.println("Stytch authentication failed");
    }
```

Comment: What is the method `convert()`?

Comment: I have a feeling you haven't actually parsed your JSON here. If you want to properly read it you will most likely want to use a JSON parsing library. I am not sure where you got `getKeyValue` from, but it definitely isn't defined for a standard `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems with your code.

1. I don't know what `convert` is, but it surely sounds like a useless library you need to ditch; the ability to turn an inputstream into a string already exists in the core libraries and there is no need to involve libraries with badly named methods. `new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is what you're looking for, all core common classes.
2. Your code is also broken in that it leaks resources. Whenever you open a resource, do so in a try-with-resources block. Failure to do so means you'll leak resources; you can't just call `inputStream.close()` someplace, or even a homegrown method like `convert`, because what if an exception happens? try-with-resources takes care of it. Looks like this:

```
try (var inputStream = http.getInputStream()) {
   // code goes here.
}
```

3. A string isn't JSON yet. It's just.. a string. You need to parse that JSON into something first.

That #3 is a bit of a doozy. You have a few options, but the one that works best with java's statically typed nature is the concept of marshalling:

You define a class (often called a 'POJO', which is short for 'plain old java object', as in, instances of such a class are POJOs) with 1 field for each element in the JSON. Type the field appropriately. Then use a library that takes your class, takes the JSON, and makes the peg fit in the hole.

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is one such library.

Review [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) for more info.

Yes, it's a dependency you'll need to include, an API you need to use and a tutorial you need to read. Java is strongly typed and JSON, being based on javascript, isn't. Interoperation is not trivial. Jackson makes it feel smooth and java-like.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get an example? when I put new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) , I get inputStream cannot be resolved.

Comment: @nananaka But `inputStream` is a variable in the very snippet you pasted!

Comment: Hi, I have added my latest code in the question. does it look good ??

Comment: @nananaka It doesn't cover _any_ of the things I mentioned, so, not really, no :(

Comment: I am not really sure what to do with try (var inputStream = http.getInputStream()) {
   // code goes here.
}

Comment: it's legal java. Just.. copy/paste it into your code. It replaces the `InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream()` part, and all the code that interacts with this 'inputStream' variable should be inside. Search the web for 'java ARM' for an explanation.

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for your advise but I get var cannot be resolved to a type. 
try (var inputStream = http.getInputStream()) {
    
  
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonContent = convert(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonContent);
       String Stytch_user_id = node.get("user_id").textValue();
   
   }

Comment: @nananaka then you're on quite an old java version. Just replace `var` with `InputStream`.